# How to send JSON response to another view in Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I have a problem with sending a JSON response from `UITableView` into another `UITableView`.

I want to send the Products array like in the code below into another `UITableViewController` based on the selected row on the TableView, but when I log the value in `didSelectRowAt` it returns `nil`.
So here's the JSON return.

```
{
  "error_description": [],
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Ernser, Kilback and Kreiger LLC",
      "address": "48788 Adaline Ville 7634 Bertram Shoal",
      "contact_person": "Coralie Schaden",
      "mobile_number": "(238) 076-0562",
      "image": {
        "url": null,
        "thumb": {
          "url": null
         },
        "medium": {
           "url": null
         },
        "small": {
          "url": null
        },
        "icon": {
           "url": null
         }
       },
      "registered_at": "2017-01-10T04:16:52.621Z",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": 21,
          "name": "Fantastic Rubber Car",
          "image": {
            "url": null,
            "thumb": {
              "url": null
            },
            "medium": {
              "url": null
            },
            "small": {
          "url": null
        },
        "icon": {
          "url": null
        }
      },
      "points": 0,
      "merchant_id": 2,
      "created_at": "2017-01-10T04:16:52.630Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-01-10T04:16:52.636Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 22,
      "name": "Mediocre Plastic Shirt",
      "image": {
        "url": null,
        "thumb": {
          "url": null
        },
        "medium": {
          "url": null
        },
        "small": {
          "url": null
        },
        "icon": {
          "url": null
        }
      },
      "points": 15,
      "merchant_id": 2,
      "created_at": "2017-01-10T04:16:52.819Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-01-10T04:16:52.827Z"
    },
  ]
  }
```

This is a part of my code for getting the response.
I used the Alamofire

```
    var merchantModel: Merchant!
    var merchantArr = [Merchant]()

    var productArr = [Product]()
    var productModel : Product?
.....
case .success:

           let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
           
           for result in json["results"].arrayValue{
               guard let merchantID = result["id"].number, let merchantName = result["name"].string, let merchantAddress = result["address"].string, let contactPerson = result["contact_person"].string, let mobilenumber = result["mobile_number"].string else{
                   
                   return
               }
               self.merchantModel = Merchant(merchantID: merchantID, merchantName: merchantName, merchantAddress: merchantAddress, contactPerson: contactPerson, mobileNumber: mobilenumber, merchantImage: contactPerson)
               
               let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(self.merchantModel!, toFile: Merchant.ArchiveURL.path)
               if !isSuccessfulSave {
                   print("Failed to save sender...")
               }
               
               
               for prodArr in result["products"].arrayValue{
                   print("prodArr:\(prodArr)")
                   guard let prodID = prodArr["id"].number, let prodName = prodArr["name"].string,
                    let points = prodArr["points"].number else{
                       
                       return
                   }
                   
                   self.productModel = Product(productID: prodID, productName: prodName, productPoints: points)
                   
               
                   
               }
               
               self.merchantArr.append(self.merchantModel!)
               self.productArr.append(self.productModel!)
               
               self.merchantModel.loadMerchant()
               self.tableView.reloadData()
           }
```

Comment: How did you try to send it to other UITableView?

Comment: I've create another product varialbe into the second controller then populate it using this approach.
       let productsView = ProductTableViewController()
        
            productsView.productArray = productArray[indexPath.row]
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(productsView, animated: false) @KrishnaCA

Comment: This should work, put a break point there and check whether it's empty and also add to this in the question

Answer (score 3):

Swift is not javascript, and JSON is not the simplest way to handle the data in this language.

You'd probably prefer to transform your JSON data into `Foundation` objects, manipulate them, create `UITableView` with them... And when you'll need to have the JSON format again, you transform those `Foundation` objects back to JSON.

There are a lot of ways to achieve that, and some amazing third-party libraries to do it very easily. However for a start I encourage you to have a look at Apple's resources :

- [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsjsonserialization)
- [Working with JSON in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37)